# How to drag DOM element inside canvas without going out of canvas with P5js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

## What I want:

I have a div and I want to move it around the canvas but limit it to canvas width and height

## What I have:

I'm using `p5.dom.js` library

P5js code:

```
let dragging = false;
let offsetX, offsetY, onsetX, onsetY;
let canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
let currentDragDiv;

function setup() {
    canvasWidth = windowWidth < 400 ? 400 : windowWidth;
    canvasHeight = windowHeight < 400 ? 400 : windowHeight;
    canvas = createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
            .mousePressed(createDiv);
}

function draw() {

    background(200);

    if(dragging){
        if(mouseX + onsetX < canvasWidth && mouseX + offsetX > 0){
            currentDragDiv.position(mouseX + offsetX, currentDragDiv.y);
        }
        if(mouseY + onsetY < canvasHeight && mouseY + offsetY > 0 ){
            currentDragDiv.position(currentDragDiv.x, mouseY + offsetY);
        } 
    }
}

function createDiv(){
    let div = createDiv("")
        .mousePressed(function(){ dragDiv(div); })
        .mouseReleased(function(){ dropDiv(div); })
        .position(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function dropDiv(){
    dragging = false;
    currentDragDiv = null;
}

function dragDiv(d){
    currentDragDiv = d;
    dragging = true;        
    offsetX = currentDragDiv.x - mouseX;
    offsetY = currentDragDiv.y - mouseY;
    onsetX = currentDragDiv.width + offsetX;
    onsetY = currentDragDiv.height + offsetY;
}
```

## The Problem:

This code is working great but if the user moves the mouse too quickly, the div doesn't go until the border of the canvas things like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIPyx.png) happens (I dragged and moved the div very fast to the right and it stoped in the middle of screen). This problem makes the variable onsetX and onsetY goes wrong and mess up a lit bit deppending on how much the div is away from the canvas border.

**Is it possible to remove this "error" and make the div go until the border of canvas?**

## Observations:

1. I removed some of the code that I think it's not necessary for this question.
2. The variables onsetX and onsetY are the oposite of offsetX and offsetY, it's the position of the border from the mouse position, but because english isn't my native language, I didn't know how to name the variable. Recommendations would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code the dragging is completely omitted, if the border of the canvas is exceeded:

```
if(mouseX + onsetX < canvasWidth && mouseX + offsetX > 0){
    currentDragDiv.position(mouseX + offsetX, currentDragDiv.y);
}
if (mouseY + onsetY < canvasHeight && mouseY + offsetY > 0 ){
    currentDragDiv.position(currentDragDiv.x, mouseY + offsetY);
}
```

Instead of that you have to limit the dragging to the range from 0 to `canvasWidth` respectively 0 to `canvasHeight`. This means you have to "clamp" the dragging to this range:

```
function draw() {
    let newX, newY;

    background(200);

    if(dragging){

        newX = mouseX + offsetX;

        if ( newX > canvasWidth ) {
            newX = canvasWidth - currentPostIt.width;
        } 
        if ( newX < 0 ) {
            newX = 0;
        }

        newY = mouseY + offsetY;

        if ( newY > canvasHeight ) {
          newY = canvasHeight - currentPostIt.height;
        } 
        if ( newY < 0 ) {
          newY = 0;
        }

        currentDragDiv.position(newX, newY);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ideia for clamp is the awnser for my case, but the code doesn't work, i send a edit to make it the correct awnser